# Por favor preciso calcular o SD por linhas diversas variaveis (colunas),

Tags: r

[image: dataframe amostra,]

Tentei loop, `apply`, como estou apreendendo, não consegui a solução, a ideia e cria uma função que calcule o `sd` esta função fornece o cálculo por linha:

```
f_sd_subgrupo <- function(dados){
  sd_subgrupo <- dados %>% 
    select(starts_with("amostra"))%>%
    apply(1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

O que busco é seguinte:

```
amostra <- data.frame(
                      subgrupo = c(rep(1:4)),
                      cartaid = 1,
                      amostra.1 = c (50.,49,48,47),
                      amostra.2 = c(51.,49.,48,49),
                      amostra.3 = c(50.,51.,48.,49),
                      amostra.4 = c(51.,50.,52.,48),
                      amostra.5 = c(49.,50.,52.,51))
```

Sd calculado na função descrita fornece o Desvio padrão a cada linha,os valores são:

```
subgrupo 01 : 1.29099   SdOverall 1.29099
subgrupo 02 : 1.50000   sdoverall 1.457738
subgrupo 03 : 1.29099   sdoverall 1.356801
subgrupo 04 : 1.707825  sdoverall 1.460593
```

Procuro uma função para calcular o seguinte:

Sdoverall que acumula a cada linha os valores da variaveis(amostras) a cada subgrupo:

Sdoverall do subgrupo 1 são todos os valores das amostras (sdoverall = 1.29099).

Sdoverall do subgrupo2 são os valores das amostras do subgrupo 1 e os valores do subgrupo 2 (1.457738).

sdoverall do subgrupo 3 são os valores das amostras do subgrupo1,subgrupo2 e do subgrupo3 (1.356801)....e continua

Não e soma, a partir do subgrupo 2, serão acrescentados os valores(amostras) do subgrupo anterior, tipo for i in 2:n,
o numero de elementos acumula, assim :
o subgrupo 2 possui os valores da linha 01(subgrupo 1) e linha 02(subgrupo 2) para calcular o desvio padrão amostral do subgrupo 2.

Obrigado

---

1. Relacionar o item

---

Comment: Não percebo como é que está a obter aqueles valores. O `sd` da primeira linha está certo mas o da 2ª linha dá `0.5567764` e a soma desse valor com o da linha anterior dá `1.074249`. E se primeiro somar as linhas e depois calcular o `sd` dá `1.072121`.

Comment: O Sd que procuro e acumulativo das variaveis, a primeira linha corresponde ao conjunto de valores da primeira amostra(sem problema de obter), o Sd da segunda linha representa o conjunto de amostras da primeira e da segunda linha, e assim sucessivamente, conjunto amostral. Sd por linhas de variaveis sem problemas, a dificuldade e obter Sd acumulativo.

Comment: Por favor edite a pergunta com a saída de `dput(head(dados, 10))`. Imagens não são uma boa forma de partilhar dados.

Comment: Obrigado pelos dados. Mas continuo a não perceber o resultado esperado, os `sd` acumulados dão `[1] 0.8366600 0.8164966 1.3557637 1.4290225`.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender e aproveitar melhor o site vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 2):

Com os dados da pergunta, o código que se segue calcula os desvios-padrões de

1. Linha 1;
2. Linhas 1 e 2;
3. Linhas 1, 2, e 3;
4. Linhas 1, 2, 3 e 4.

Mas os resultados não correspondem aos resultados na pergunta.

```
i_col <- grep('^amostra', names(amostra))

sapply(seq_len(nrow(amostra)), function(i){
  x <- amostra[seq_len(i), i_col]
  x <- unlist(x)
  sd(x)
})
#[1] 0.8366600 0.8164966 1.3557637 1.4290225
```

O código acima pode ser reescrito como função.

1. A função tem 3 argumentos,

   1. a base `x`, um data.frame;
   2. as colunas onde estão os valores cujo desvio padrão deve ser calculado;
   3. se os valores `NA` devem ser removidos.
2. na primeira instrução, aplica a cada uma das linhas de `x` uma função anónima;
3. essa função extrai as `i` primeiras linhas e as colunas em questão no objeto `y`;
4. `y` pode ser um data.frame, portanto é transformado em vetor;
5. o desvio padrão é calculado e é a saída da função.

Como a base é o primeiro argumento, esta função pode ser usada num *pipe* do pacote `magrittr`.

```
sdAcum <- function(x, cols, na.rm = FALSE){
  sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i){
    y <- x[seq_len(i), cols]
    y <- unlist(y)
    sd(y, na.rm = na.rm)
  })
}

sdAcum(amostra, i_col)    # mesmo resultado
```

Com o pacote `dplyr`, a primeira forma de chamar a função devolve um vetor, a segunda forma um data.frame.

```
amostra %>% sdAcum(i_col)

amostra %>%
  mutate(Sdoverall = sdAcum(., i_col))
```

Comment: @Caco se a resposta resolve o poblema, dê uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Aceitar a resposta serve para ser mais facilmente encontrada por outros usuários que tenham a mesma dúvida.